# In which folder can I store user uploaded images

Tags: asp.net, restart

I've a classified ads system on ASP.NET/c#/MS SQL, and I'm trying to figure out where to store the images that people upload when placing an ad. The ad itself is being stored in a SQL server database.

The images are now being stored in a subfolder of my webapp. It seems to work fine, however I only recently discovered a big problem. Everytime a user deletes an ad, the attached images are to be deleted as well including the folder they reside in. This leads to a restart of the asp.net application. I searched internet and found that restarting the web-app is actually intended behaviour when a subfolder is being deleted.

Obviously, I need to fix this. But how to do that? Where can I store images in such a way that:

- I can remove these images including the folders they are stored in?
- I can acces them using a URL (the images need to be shown in the
  webpages)
- Without getting the web-app being
  restarted?
  Any feedback is appreciated!
  Paul

Answer (score 0):

See this question [Deleting a directory results in application restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502743/asp-net-deleting-a-directory-results-in-application-restart)

An other alternative would be to store the images in the DB instead.

Comment: Deleting a directory ... yeah I found that out the hard way ... Storing in the DB? That would make the DB very large and expensive. I'd prefer to prevent that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to put the images in a directory completely unrelated to the web site then serve the images through a scripted page or handler. It would make all of your image urls look like `mydomaincom/serveimage.aspx?imageid=323422`, but unless you're counting on the name somewhere that really shouldn't matter much. Obviously it would require a modification to the page that serves the images in the first place as well, but if sub directories of this unrelated directory are deleted IIS really shouldn't care at all.

Comment: Writing a custom handler? That sounds perfect solution. I put the folder with all the ads images somewhere outside the webapp folder ... I'll have to think it through a bit .. file upload needs to change, ad.view, ad.publish, ad.delete ... One worry would be if my 'custom' handler written in c# would be less efficient than the default, optimised one, I'm using right now ... Maybe, I Should  think about a setting up a url rewrite in a httpmodule, so I can maintain the default image handlers?

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can store the images in SQL (check at the filestream feature in this case)
if not, I suppose you have somewhere in a business facade class, a service class or wherever you want, a methode "DeleteAd".

This method will have to do two things :

-delete the sql data
-delete the file image

also, you may change the image store to another folder, outside the web app. You will probably end with writing a custom handler (myhandler.ashx?fileid=XX) to serve the files, or a custom route and control if you use MVC.

Comment: Since the ad itself is already stored in the database, I think storing the images there too would be a good solution.

Comment: you just have to be careful on the performance impact. Storing images in a DB will be a lot slower than pure file access. That's why I suggested to use the filestream feature of SQL 2008. You can also rely of the asp.net cache mechanism, or a combination of the two.

Comment: Thanx Steve and Koen. Storing the image in the DB would be great, logical ... but I cannot see it as a good performaing solution. Besides, the database would grow enormously.  FYI the size of the database without the images is only 10% of the folder that contains the images.