# ASP.NET Session Lost on Directory MoveTo

Tags: asp.net, session, io

I have a web app. When I create a client I upload some pictures in that process to a temp folder I create using the Ticks. Finally, when the client in created I move that folder to the main folder of clients pictures whith the name of the client Id I just get.

```
DirectoryInfo dirTemp = new DirectoryInfo(String.Concat(sPath, "temp/", sTicks));
dirTemp.MoveTo(String.Concat(sPath, sName));
```

My folders structure is this:

```
sPath = "~/Files/Clients/"
```

The problem is I'm losing the `Session` everytime I move the folder...

Comment: what do you mean by losing the session? any error to share or any strange behavior you have detected? how do you access the session before and after the move and why do you think it has been lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you **move/delete/add a directory** in your appDomain - your **current session** will be **destroyed**.

Try to move a directory that is not within your application folders - that should do the trick! If this is no proper solution for your problem **change** your **sessionState** mode. Currently, I assume, it is InProc. Change it to *StateServer* or *SQLServer*. 
(see also [Forums ASP](http://forums.asp.net/p/1372202/2872030.aspx))

Furthermore - possible duplicate? - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803493/asp-net-loses-session-data-when-delete-directory-on-webapplications)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the app pool is being recycled due to your changes, and that causes all session data to be discarded.

Comment: Thanks man, you are rigth, the problem is when you rename or delete a folder inside the app path the session recicles...