# ASP.NET 4.5 -- Application pool restart when sub-directory is deleted in a virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Just to preface, before I decided to ask this question, I have searched up and down StackOverflow.

The problem I am having is w/r/t to deleting sub-directories in an ASP.NET web application and it causing an application pool restart.

The folder that we upload files into, as well as delete/create sub-directories in, is off the root of the application and setup as a virtual directory in IIS.

A zip can be uploaded the contains html and images. We show a preview of the html as well as the images.

The user can re-upload another zip. When this happens, we delete the previous temporary folder, and then create another temporary folder to hold the contents of the zip and render another preview.

It's during the deletion of the previous folder that we see an app restart. The snippet of the log output is:

```
2014-02-10 16:06:45,240 [16] global_asax - Application_End(): CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
```

We've had this setup from when our application used to run under ASP.NET 2.0 and this was the 'recommended' setup to avoid application pool restarts and creating/deleting directories.

We've recently upgraded our web application to ASP.NET 4.5 and we are seeing this behavior in our development environment.

Based on this post, http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646824/asp-net-application-restart-ignore-folder-setting, which says that ASP.NET 4 has relaxed on the monitoring for directory changes when the folders are under the web root as well as this post, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx, which states that a change to the physical structure of a virtual directory can cause an application pool restart. I've moved the folders back under the web root but I am still seeing the behavior.

What's interesting is that if we comment out the piece of code that creates the preview (An iFrame that renders the html which will reference any images uploaded with the zip to its temporary location i.e.: domain.com/temp/2//images/header.gif. The deletion happens with no application restart.

Any help, or advice of where to look next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502743/asp-net-deleting-a-directory-results-in-application-restart ?

Comment: Yes. I tried linkd/mlink/junction. They worked, but created a problem another problem. If you requested say image that you just uploaded, then re-uploaded another image to the same path with the same name (part of our application allows for this) -- IIS would hold onto it and show that image each time when requested. An IIS reset was needed or a tweak to a reg setting to disable memory caching for IIS to stop it completely.

Comment: What if you create non-asp.net iis web application or virtual folder for that files?

Comment: One of the replies in Anri's link mentions disabling the filesystem watch by reflection. This has worked flawlessly for me in asp.net 2.0 to 3.5, though I have not tried it in 4.0 or later yet

Comment: We have same thing happening here, also on FW 4.5